# what is minimum required size of /boot partition for Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, raid, boot-partition

Because I don't want "why?" as response, I will start with the background.

I wanted to make a software RAID-0 of 2 disks since they are quite slow and small in size because they are very old. So I want to spare minimum amount of space for /boot partition at the beginning of the drive. I did search and found that Linux in general uses between 128mb to 2.5gb and for Ubuntu about 250mb to 1gb. But since I know what I'm installing (Ubuntu 18.04.2 x64 alternate) I wanted to know a number that is little bit more precise than 250mb to 1gb.

So to the question: What is minimum required size of /boot partition for Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Comment: I hava a clean `bionic` installation with a few installed applications such as browsers, mail clients, it's around 6.5GB

Comment: What you read is wrong for Ubuntu. Even Ubuntu 14.04 takes 4GB at minimum

Comment: no, not entire system size. I mean just /boot partition size.

Comment: If you do everything yourself (rather than use the installer) I am sure you could probably get away with 256MiB-512MiB. As for a specific number, that is a question only you can answer as it is **your** system which will be different to mine/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean and what you want. Boot partition and `/boot` directory in Ubuntu filesystem are two different things

Comment: @j-money thanks a lot I didn't realize that every system may require different size

Comment: @kenn /boot directory is like windows folder for windows installation. It contains system information required at boot time and cannot be striped with raid-0

Comment: I know the function of `/boot` directory, it contains linux kernel, initial ramdisk, grub folder, etc. Size of it for `bionic` is around 45MB.

Comment: Are you going to upgrade, do you want to keep the last kernel as backup boot option when upgrading? I have a small /boot it's been annoying as anything.

Comment: FWIW my current /boot is at 146M used out of 226M, but I wouldn't make it less than 512MB if doing it again; cf https://serverfault.com/questions/334663/what-is-the-recommended-size-for-a-linux-boot-partition

Comment: It depends on how many old kernels you will keep in your boot partition. Are you a "neat freak" or "safety first" kind of guy?

Answer (score 2):

> What is minimum required size of /boot partition for Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Update: for Ubuntu 22.04 and later, [I now recommend **2 GiB**](https://serverfault.com/a/1029458/357116). Even **3 GiB** would be better to allow for more Linux kernels and system upgrades over time.

---

Original answer: **732.00 MiB.** I just did an Ubuntu 20.04 install on a completely empty disk and I let it do all the partitioning stuff. I chose the options for "LVM" and "encrypted partition" or whatever, then looked at `gparted` to see what partition scheme it produced. Here's what I saw on my 512GiB drive:

```
Partition   Name                    File System          Mount Point        Size        Used        Unused      Flags
---------   ----                    -----------          -----------        ----------  ----------  ----------  -----
/dev/sda1   EFI System Partition    fat32                /target/boot/efi   512.00 MiB    1.02 MiB  510.98 MiB  boot,esp
/dev/sda2   (none)                  ext4                 /target/boot       732.00 MiB   47.66 MiB  684.34 MiB  (none)
/dev/sda3   (none)                  [Encrypted] lvm2 pv  vgubuntu           475.72 GiB  475.72 GiB    0.00 B    (none)
```

So, it gave the `/target/boot` partition 732.00 MiB. If I was doing this manually, I'd just give it **1 GiB** and call it good.

Update: I've posted this on ServerFault too: [What is the recommended size for a Linux /boot partition?](https://serverfault.com/a/1029458/357116)